# Ingress nginx on Kind cluster on Windows 10 throws Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image

Tags: windows, nginx, kubernetes, kind

I run Kind on my windows machine and use the following configuration for my local nodes

```
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
  - role: control-plane
    kubeadmConfigPatches:
      - |
        kind: InitConfiguration
        nodeRegistration:
          kubeletExtraArgs:
            node-labels: "ingress-ready=true"
    extraPortMappings:
      - containerPort: 80
        hostPort: 80
        protocol: TCP
      - containerPort: 443
        hostPort: 443
        protocol: TCP
  - role: worker
  - role: worker
  - role: worker
```

Afer running

```
kind create cluster --name dev --config .\kind-cluster.yaml
```

I can see that the nodes were created succesfully

```
kubectl get nodes -owide
NAME                STATUS   ROLES           AGE     VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION                       CONTAINER-RUNTIME
dev-control-plane   Ready    control-plane   2m28s   v1.25.3   172.19.0.5    <none>        Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS   5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2   containerd://1.6.9
dev-worker          Ready    <none>          111s    v1.25.3   172.19.0.3    <none>        Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS   5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2   containerd://1.6.9
dev-worker2         Ready    <none>          2m3s    v1.25.3   172.19.0.2    <none>        Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS   5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2   containerd://1.6.9
dev-worker3         Ready    <none>          110s    v1.25.3   172.19.0.4    <none>        Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS   5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2   containerd://1.6.9
```

As a next step I am trying to create ingress by running

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/
static/provider/kind/deploy.yaml
```

The output seems to be fine

```
namespace/ingress-nginx created
serviceaccount/ingress-nginx created
serviceaccount/ingress-nginx-admission created
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx created
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx-admission created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx-admission created
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx created
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx-admission created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx-admission created
configmap/ingress-nginx-controller created
service/ingress-nginx-controller created
service/ingress-nginx-controller-admission created
deployment.apps/ingress-nginx-controller created
job.batch/ingress-nginx-admission-create created
job.batch/ingress-nginx-admission-patch created
ingressclass.networking.k8s.io/nginx created
validatingwebhookconfiguration.admissionregistration.k8s.io/ingress-nginx-admission created
```

If I run

```
kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx -owide
NAME                                       READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE   IP           NODE                NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
ingress-nginx-admission-create-5s2x5       0/1     ErrImagePull        0          34s   10.244.1.2   dev-worker2         <none>           <none>
ingress-nginx-admission-patch-h7px4        0/1     ErrImagePull        0          34s   10.244.2.2   dev-worker          <none>           <none>
ingress-nginx-controller-6bccc5966-xqcqc   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          34s   <none>       dev-control-plane   <none>           <none>
```

In Lens, I can see the following error message on worker nodes

```
Failed to pull image "registry.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v20220916-gd32f8c343@sha256:39c5b2e3310dc4264d638ad28d9d1d96c4cbb2b2dcfb52368fe4e3c63f61e10f": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "registry.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen@sha256:39c5b2e3310dc4264d638ad28d9d1d96c4cbb2b2dcfb52368fe4e3c63f61e10f": failed to resolve reference "registry.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen@sha256:39c5b2e3310dc4264d638ad28d9d1d96c4cbb2b2dcfb52368fe4e3c63f61e10f": failed to do request: Head "https://registry.k8s.io/v2/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen/manifests/sha256:39c5b2e3310dc4264d638ad28d9d1d96c4cbb2b2dcfb52368fe4e3c63f61e10f": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

While on control panel node, the error is different

```
Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[webhook-cert], unattached volumes=[webhook-cert kube-api-access-6hfr9]: timed out waiting for the condition
```

and

```
MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "webhook-cert" : secret "ingress-nginx-admission" not found
```

Trying to figure out what would be the root cause.

Comment: Did you find any solution for it?

Comment: Nope, I switched to hproxy